# Cluster robust standard error

Tags: panel-data, autocorrelation, heteroscedasticity, clustered-standard-errors, robust-standard-error

$$\bf{y}=\bf{X\beta}+\bf{\epsilon}$$
In asymptotic setting, assume:
(a) linearity
(b) $\{y_i,\bf{x}_i\}$ ergodic stationarity
(c) weak exogeneity $E(\bf{x}_i\epsilon_i)=0$
(d) Rank condition $E(\bf{x}_i\bf{x}_i^{'})$ is nonsingular

(1) assume (e) asymptotic normality of $\sqrt{n}\overline{\bf g}_n:\sqrt{n}\overline{\bf g}_n \sim N(0, S)$,
where $\overline{\bf g}_n = \frac{1}{n} \sum \bf{g}_i$ and $\bf{g}_i=\bf{x}_i\epsilon_i$, $\bf{g}_i$ is a  martingale difference sequence with finite second moments.

To deal with heteroskadasticity (and assume independence),
$$
S=AVar(\overline{\bf g}_n) = E(\bf{g}_i\bf{g}_i^{'}) = E(\epsilon^2_i\bf{x}_i\bf{x}_i^{'})
$$

This can be estimated by
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum \hat{\epsilon}^2_i\bf{x}_i\bf{x}_i^{'}
$$

(2) To deal with heteroskadasticity and within group (within $i$) correlation (i.e., $E(g_{it}g_{is})\neq0$ but $E(g_{it}g_{js})=0, i \neq j$), so $\bf{g}_{it}$ is not a  martingale difference sequence, and say this is panel data with group i and time t.
$$S=E(\bf{g}_i\bf{g}_i^{'})=E(\bf{h}_i\bf{h}_i^{'})$$
where $\bf{h}_i=\sum_{t}^{T}g_{it}$ has the same property as $\bf{g}_i$ in (1),
so $S$ can be estimate by
$$
\frac{1}{nT}\sum_{i}^{n}\hat{\bf{h}}_i\hat{\bf{h}}_i^{'} = \frac{1}{nT}\sum_{i}^{n}[(\sum_{t}\bf{x}_{it}\hat{\epsilon}_{it})(\sum_{t}\bf{x}_{it}\hat{\epsilon}_{it})^{'}]
$$

My question is

1. Why cannot I just estimate $S$ in (2) as in (1), such as $\hat{S}=\frac{1}{nT}\sum x_{it}^2\hat{\epsilon_{it}}^2$?
2. I suppose it is because of the correlation, I cannot simply sum them up observation by observation, but why can one do $\sum_{t}\bf{x}_{it}\hat{\epsilon}_{it}$ in (2)?

Notation from ['Econometrics' by Hayashi](https://press.princeton.edu/books/hardcover/9780691010182/econometrics).

Comment: OK, improved now, but I still don't understand what "groups" you refer to. Or rather, the original model formulation doesn't have groups in it, and if $i$ refers to a group, you haven't defined observations within groups.

Comment: lets say the original model is for cross section data in (1) and panel data in (2)..